# Launching WORD document and Jump directly to a specific section using Python

Tags: python, docx

I have to do some processing with WORD docs , for instance I would like to open the doc which i successfully did with something like this :

```
try:
    os.startfile(filename_path)
except AttributeError:
   ...
```

Now this opens the word doc as expected but instead of putting the cursor at the beginning of the doc, I want to open the doc to a specific section(or heading). Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Hacky solution: With Pyautogui you can emulate a keyboard. after opening the word document press Ctrl+G to open Go To menu, then shift+Tab to select the "Go to what" section, Down Arrow to select Section, Tab to select section number, input the section number and press Enter.

Comment: look into this library:  [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) (i've used it for interacting with Outlook but not for Word).

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  I was not aware of __PyAutoGUI__, so thanks for introducing it here and it could work but see answer below for a less "hacky" solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample code to open word at a specified location (bookmark, page_number, comment, field, etc.):

```
import win32com.client as win32

path_file_name = <insert path and filename> # "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\test.docx"
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
doc = word.Documents.Open(path_file_name, ReadOnly=False)
doc.Activate()

word.Selection.GoTo(What=0, Count=2)  # go to Section_2
# word.Selection.GoTo(What=-1, Name="world")  # go to Bookmark named "world"
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.goto) for *parameters* and *values*.   Example **"What"** values are: `-1 for Bookmark`, `0 for Section`, `1 for Page`, `11 for Heading`.